# vba vlookup returns values stored as text

Tags: vba

What is wrong with this code? When run it returns good values but their formatting is bad - values are stored as text

```
For i = 2 To nrow
For j = 2 To ncol
    With Worksheets(j - 1)
        Set rang= .Range("A:F")
        End With

Dim wart As Variant
wart = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), rang, 6, False)
Cells(i, j) = wart
If IsError(Cells(i, j)) Then Cells(i, j) = 0
Cells(i, j) = Format(Cells(i, j), "Percent")
```

When data type of     wart    is changed to Double - "type mismatch" error appears

Answer (score 1):

Formatting was done wrong!
`Format(Cells(i, j), "Percent")` doesn't seem right

Replace `Cells(i, j) = Format(Cells(i, j), "Percent")` with `Cells(i, j).NumberFormat= "0.00%"`

Also make sure you set the value if the cell by `Cells(i, j).Value = wart`.